# Right way of comparing my model's result with state of the arts

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, dataset, model-comparison, research-design

I know that I have to use the same datasets and experimental settings. In this way, I don't have to run their codes. What if I used different datasets? Is it OK to use their code from GitHub to get the accuracy for the specific dataset? If so, how do I find the best code that will run without many errors? Because I spent a lot of time running those codes with many parts that I didn't understand and many errors that I could not fix. Wondering to know what is the easiest way or most commonly used in research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way out of this. Most researchers share their code such that it can be run assuming an input format. If you want to use it with your data, you either need to adapt their code or adapt your data. The first way is usually more challenging because you need to understand their code.

Comment: Thanks dear. I have one more question, if I have X and Y datasets and if I will apply few-sho- learning by training the model on X dataset and applying meta-testing using Y dataset. While I compare my result with others, can I use their pre-trained model and test it on Y dataset or do I have to train their model first on X dataset and then test it on Y dataset? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I guess I missed this one. I think it deserves another post with few shot learning tag.